# Automate VMware Snapshots and remove snapshots older than 5 days

Tags: powershell, backup, vmware, powercli

I have 3 VMware exi 6.5 hosts each running 4 virtual machines.

In Powershell using PowerCLI, I would like a script that connects to a VMware esxi 6.5 host, executes a snapshot (excluding memory) of each VM, naming it the Day and Time, then removing / consolidating snapshots older than 2 days. The plan is to run the script everyday, to have a quick rollback point, should ransom-ware infect the server.

Thank you very much, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a good application for a script. What do you have so far, and where are you stuck? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/430138/ - "*A Snapshot is not a differential image, it's a change log, so if you write the same data on the same place 10 times, the snapshot will increase it's size by 10 multiplied the size of data you wrote.*" and "*This means, that read accesses would have to read not only one file, but also all difference data (the original data plus every change made to the original data). The number increases even more when you cascade snapshots.*". This idea slows down all your servers, but gains you nothing more than a nightly differential backup does.

Comment: @alroc, I am not sure where to start with this, this is why I posted it in stack overflow, I have seen the commands in PowerCLI to take snapshots, but am not sure how to get them to run from powershell.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, Thank you, I am aware of the role and performance a snapshot takes, hence only keeping 2 snapshots and my reasoning for wanting it is I can revert back to the morning or previous day in 3 clicks and 5 minutes, rather than 12+ hours to restore 8TB of data from backup.

Comment: PowerCLI *is* a PowerShell module, so if you've "seen the commands", that's what you need to do to "get them to run from powershell." And SO is still not a code-writing service, so try a few things and when you get stuck on a specific piece of code, ask questions about that.

Comment: If ransomware encrypts all your data, your snapshots will grow with every encrypted file write, no limit. How many TB of free space do you have, because when snapshots fills the datastore, all your VMs will be unable to write to disk at all, and they will *all* crash; VMware cannot delete snapshots when the datastore is full. I've done that, it's not fun. A good backup solution (e.g. Veeam) can do a differential restore of just the block changes since last night, and it can do an instant-on recovery, running a VM from the backup store then storage migrate the disks while the VM is live.

Comment: Anyway, you install PowerCLI, and `Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core` and just write PowerShell as normal, using the Vmware commands as well - including `Connect-ViServer` and so on. e.g. http://danstechnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/vmware-snapshot-auto-delete-powershell.html and https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2016/02/create-and-restore-multiple-vm-snapshots-at-once/ ideas

Answer (score 0):

Below is a PowerShell function that I use for VMWare **Workstation**. You will need to research the `vmrun` command to find out more details of how to adapt it to your needs for ESX; this will get you on the right track. I realize this is not leveraging PowerShellCLI.

```
function Execute-VMRunCmd{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$args = $(Throw "Args parameter is required.")
    )
    WriteToLog -msg "VMRun Args: $args"
    pushd $sourcePath
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = $vmwareRun
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = "$args"
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    $procExitCode = [string]$p.ExitCode
    popd
    WriteToLog -msg "stdout: $stdout, stderr: $stderr, ExitCode: $procExitCode"
    return $stdout
}
```

`WriteToLog` is a function that I created to handle logging that inserts a timestamp, but it is a simple `$fullMsg | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append -NoClobber` call.

`$sourcepath` is the folder path to the vmx file, for ESX you will need to modify this. I switch to the directory for some of the calls to work. For ESX I suspect that this will not be required.

`$vmwareRun` is the path to your vmrun executable.

Vmrun command line documentation is found here: "https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_vmrun_command.pdf"

I can use the above command to automate the vmrun command. I also return the `$stdout` value in case you need to evaluate the output of things like `listsnapshots`

Below is an example of how I utilize this function.

```
function Update-Snapshot{
    $snapshotName="WeeklyUpdate"

    [string]$allSnapshots = Execute-VMRunCmd -args "listSnapshots $fqp_source"
    if ($allSnapshots.Contains($snapshotName)){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 
        Execute-VMRunCmd -args "deleteSnapshot $fqp_source $snapshotName"
    }
    Execute-VMRunCmd -args "snapshot `"$fqp_source`" $snapshotName"
}
```

Note that I had to insert an arbitrary sleep command. For some reason I was getting `host not available` error when trying to delete a snapshot without it. I have not figured out why yet.

Read through the documentation for VMRun. Hopefully this is helpful for you.